# simplifying complex expression

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, special-functions

Hi I am trying to simplify the following expression:$$
\left|\frac{1}{a+ib}\left(\frac{J_1(c x)}{J_1(c b)}-x\right)\right|^2,\quad a,b,x\in \mathbb{R}, \ c\in \mathbb{C}
$$
Is there a simple way of simplifying this ?  Note, for an arbitrary complex number $z=x+iy$ we can write
$$
|z|^2=z\bar z=(x+iy)(x-iy)=x^2+y^2
$$
however, I am not sure how to use that so clearly here because of the Bessel function.

Note, $J_1$ is the Bessel function.  Thanks.

Comment: $$\left|\frac{1}{a+ib}\left(\frac{J_1(c x)}{J_1(c b)}-x\right)\right|^2=\left|\frac{\frac{J_1(c x)}{J_1(c b)}-x}{a+bi}\right|^2=$$

$$\left(\frac{\left|\frac{J_1(c x)}{J_1(c b)}-x\right|}{\left|a+bi\right|}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\left|\frac{J_1(c x)}{J_1(c b)}-x\right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2=$$

$$\left(\frac{\left|\frac{xJ_1(c b)-J_1(c x)}{J_1(c b)}\right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\frac{\left|xJ_1(c b)-J_1(c x)\right|}{\left|J_1(c b)\right|}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2=$$

$$\frac{\left(\frac{\left|xJ_1(c b)-J_1(c x)\right|}{\left|J_1(c b)\right|}\right)^2}{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: What prcesses, or expressions, have been attempted to reduce $J_{1}(c x) - x \, J_{1}(c b)$ ?

Comment: How can you simplify the term $|xJ_1(cb)-J_1(cx)|^2$? Thank you.